# weird swift error after upgrading from 1.1 to 1.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

My project prior to the update was working fine with swift 1.1 and Xcode 6.1.1. i just upgraded to swift 1.2 and get a weird error in my AppDelegate

```
 func application(application:UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo:NSDictionary)
```

and also in a class derived from `UITextFieldDelegate`

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool // called textfield for locationField clicked
```

saying something along the lines

> Objective-C method 'application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:'
>   provided by method 'application(*:didReceiveRemoteNotification:)'
>   conflicts with optional requirement method
>   'application(*:didReceiveRemoteNotification:)' in protocol
>   'UIApplicationDelegate'

the error for the textFieldDidBeginEditing is the same:

> Objective-C method 'textFieldDidBeginEditing:' provided by method
>   'textFieldDidBeginEditing' conflicts with optional requirement method
>   'textFieldDidBeginEditing' in protocol 'UITextFieldDelegate'

What is the issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just rewrite the method's name (should fix itself), and copy/paste the code in the methods. This should work.

Comment: so tired, didn't cross my mind to try that. I think that's a sign to stop for today..

Comment: i do not understand, why rewrite the methods name?

Comment: Not exactly rewriting the method, but just the begining of it and then pressing ENTER to autocomplete it. The problem occoured because some parameters changed, and the autocomplete fixes it.

Comment: @DejanSkledar Same issue and wasted 2hrs unless i found this. worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

Before:

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool
```

After:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool!
```